# Get pseudo xml inside xml structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have some third party xml, that I'm trying to parse.

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443421/innertext-from-xelement) in that I'm looking to get at pseudo xml code buried inside one of the elements. However, the result I need is different.

Here's the xml that's returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <PostApplication_V6Response xmlns="http://xxxService.org/">
          <PostApplication_V6Result>string</PostApplication_V6Result>
        </PostApplication_V6Response>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using Linq to XML - I can return the element `<PostApplication_V6Result>` - this is the lowesst element in the tree I can retrieve.

Using this code:

```
    var name = "{http://xxxService.org/}PostApplication_V6Result";

    var soap = XDocument.Parse(result)
        .Descendants(name)
        .First();
```

However, the value contained within that element is some kind of pseudo xml - not xml but xml lookalike.

Here's what's contained inside:

```
<xxxService>
    <Application>
        <Status>Accepted</Status>
        <RedirectUrl>http://www.google.com?abc=123</RedirectUrl>
        <Value>100</Value>
    </Application>
</xxxService>
```

I've tried just about everything to get the data out, but I get either an invalid char '=' error or a data at root invalid message.

Ideally I want to get the data including within the "Application" node into a state where I can run it through a generic parser like the one below, but if I have to do something manually I will. I've been trying to solve this for a couple of days now.

```
public static T Deserialise<T>(this XElement element)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE

Here's the full xml thats returned- as you can see the inner portion is in fact html not xml.

```
<soap:body><postapplication_v6response xmlns="http://xxxService.org/"><postapplication_v6result>&lt;xxxService&gt;
&lt;Application&gt;
&lt;Status&gt;PURCHASED&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;RedirectURL&gt;http://www.google.com?test=abc&amp;xyz=123&lt;/RedirectURL&gt;
&lt;/Application&gt;
&lt;/xxxService&gt;
</postapplication_v6result></postapplication_v6response></soap:body></soap:envelope>
```

Comment: can you post the full xml? it sounds like your service is not returning valid xml?

Comment: if the content of the node is a string which contains xml characters you should wrap it in a [CData] or escape it

Comment: @Ewan - added the code Ewan - as you can see, the inner portion is html, not xml.

Comment: ok thats fine, just use innerText and deescape it like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203485/built-in-net-function-for-unescaping-characters-in-xml-stream

Comment: @Ewan - I'm still getting  aproblem with the '=' is the data when I try to reparse it. I'm doing this to get at the application node.

Comment: Ultimately I need to get the fields into a class, so I can use them.

Comment: why would you encode an object as html?

Comment: if you can get a wsdl for this service visual studio will do it all for you. just add a webservice reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side effect of decoding the entire string is, some XML special characters (`&` char in this case) that need to be kept encoded, they are get decoded resulting in an invalid XML. For this simple case, replacing `&` with `&amp;` should fix it :

```
var xml = @"<PostApplication_V6Result>
&lt;xxxService&gt;
&lt;Application&gt;
&lt;Status&gt;PURCHASED&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;RedirectURL&gt;http://www.google.com?test=abc&amp;xyz=123&lt;/RedirectURL&gt;
&lt;/Application&gt;
&lt;/xxxService&gt;
</PostApplication_V6Result>";
var soap = XElement.Parse(xml);

var rawContent = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(soap.FirstNode.ToString().Trim())
                            .Replace("&", "&amp;");
var content = XElement.Parse(rawContent);
```

Modify the code to encode [other XML special characters](http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html) if needed.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help - har07, you have the final and complete answer that works, but Ewan you get an upvote from me too.

Comment: hmmm. I'd worry that xml != html with the ampersands escaped. but why html in the first place?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. (I've taken out the namespaces) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Class7
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void xmltest()
        { 
            string xml = @"<body><postapplication_v6response><postapplication_v6result>&lt;xxxService&gt;
&lt;Application&gt;
&lt;Status&gt;PURCHASED&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;RedirectURL&gt;http://www.google.com?test=abc&amp;xyz=123&lt;/RedirectURL&gt;
&lt;/Application&gt;
&lt;/xxxService&gt;
</postapplication_v6result></postapplication_v6response></body>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            string encodedhtml = doc.Descendants("postapplication_v6result")
                    .First().Value;

            string decodedhtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedhtml);

            Console.WriteLine(decodedhtml);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ewan, please see my last answer - I have the result but it needs parsing itself to be any use.

Comment: you need a html parser library. ill have a look